# Execute simple script before shutdown and reboot

Tags: debian, init-script, sysvinit, rc

I need to run a script before shutting down or rebooting my VPS running Debian 8,to keep count of network statistics.I tried adding the script directly to `/etc/init.d` and symlinking it in `/etc/rc0.d` and `/etc/rc6.d`, and adding to it the LSB header, making it like an actual service with start and stop and generating the symlinks with update-rc.d, but nothing has worked, it seems like the script isn't executed at all.Maybe it could have to do with it being an VPS, so it doesn't get recognised by the system when it is apparently shut down or rebooted.

I just need a simple mechanism,without having to create a proper service. Also I'd like to know which could be the better way to check if the script is actually being executed or not,some simple way of logging.
The script is just this:

```
RESULT=$(bc <<< "scale =2;($(cat /sys/class/net/venet0/statistics/rx_bytes)/1024/1024/1024)+($(cat /sys/class/net/venet0/statistics/tx_bytes)/1024/1024/1024)+($(cat /root/bw))")
echo $RESULT > /root/bw
```

Comment: Can you see your service mentioned in `/etc/init.d/.depend.*`? Are you running SysV init or systemd?

Comment: Yes, it appears in /etc/init.d/.depend.stop.What do you mean with which I'm running?

Comment: Then your script seems to be installed correctly. Does it work if you invoke it (as root) via `service YOURSERVICENAME stop`? If yes, put in a `sleep 60` command for example, that gives you a noticeable delay during shutdown if executed. Pay attention to use `stop`, that's the only argument used on runlevels 0 and 6 (see `/usr/share/doc/sysv-rc/README.runlevels.gz`). If you run `systemd` as PID 1 (see `ps 1`), there are other options, but the above should work as well.

Comment: `service SERVICENAME stop` doesn't work, but `/etc/init.d/SERVICENAME stop` does.Yes, it seems I'm running systemd, PID 1 is `init -z` but it is a symlink to `/lib/systemd/systemd`.I don't think I would notice the delay, since because of it being a VPS I guess, doing `reboot`, `init 6` or whatever doesn't output anything and anyway it just stays like that for a while until it says (when I press some key) that the connection was lost.

Comment: I've managed to get it to work with systemd,but it seems that the net statistics are wiped before the script is run.Is there anything I can do about that?

Comment: You don't tell what you did, so it's hard to tell what could be wrong with it. The `service` vs `/etc/init.d/` thing is very suspicious, and the systemd stuff might be another totally different story.

Comment: I already gave up on SysV.I created a simple unit like this: `[Unit]
Description=...
DefaultDependencies=no
Before=shutdown.target reboot.target halt.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/root/script
Type=oneshot

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target`

Comment: @user2859982 Wouldn't you want the script symlinked in /etc/rc3.d as well for start-up? Also a simple but necessary question, does your script have execute permissions enabled?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works for me as `/etc/systemd/system/netstat.service`:

```
[Unit]
Description=Save interface stats on shutdown

[Service]
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=yes
ExecStart=/bin/true
ExecStop=/bin/sh -c '{ date; ip -s link; } >>/root/ipstat.log'

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Enable it with `systemctl enable netstat`. This won't give you precise statistics, because the network interfaces can still be used during shutdown, but that may be acceptable for you.

Comment: It seems it didn't work.The service was started, I don't know if at shutdown or at boot: `sep 11 10:56:42 Otroservidor systemd[1]: Starting Save interface stats on shutdown... sep 11 10:56:42 Otroservidor systemd[1]: Started Save interface stats on shutdown.`

Comment: This service should be started during bootup. But this is a purely administrative step, only to have something around to stop during shutdown.

Comment: It finally worked.Thank you very much.Could you briefly comment how/why it works? I swear I ended up trying something very similar (I don't know anything about systemd scripts), maybe save for the Before=...

Comment: This defines a normal service (`DefaultDependencies=yes`), which is started after system initialization and stopped prior to system shutdown (see `man systemd.service` for details). It does nothing but registering on start, and does its work on stop. The `Before` setting did not help you, because you started your service during system startup (`WantedBy=multi-user.target`), not shutdown (which would be another, different way to solve your problem).

Comment: there is a typo ,not ExecStart=/bin/true,but ExecStart=/bin/bash

Comment: Why do you think so, @it_is_a_literature? `ExecStart=/bin/true` looks just fine for me.

Comment: For some reason this is the only one script that works for running a script before shutdown/reboot. I tried others that seemed to have the same pieces but didn't work :sigh:

Answer (score 0):

Well, I use an ugly hack by calling my script from `/etc/rc.d/init.d/network`. This will give you statistics whenever network goes up/down/restart or system is halted/shutdown.

Don't really know if this is a good practice or not does work though.

Comment: `/etc/rc.d/init.d/network` doesn't exist in my system.Maybe it's specific to some distro?

Comment: paste an "ls" of your rc6.d here. you must have a script that deals with network connections.

Comment: on debian7 i have this file K08networking in rc6.d which is symlinked to ../init.d/networking. its behavior is same. my script runs successfully. 
Oh and the correct path for this deb7 is
/etc/rc6.d/
/etc/init.d/

Comment: Ok `/etc/rc6.d/K08networking` exists here too.Where am I supposed to call the script from in the file? It looks kind of complicated.

Comment: add it after the first line that says #!/bin/bash -e .

Comment: I'll have to test it more, but it seems it worked,not after the shebang,but adding it to the stop) case.Will accept the answer if it works fine.